# Instantiating in Verilog

Tags: verilog

I have the follow Verilog code. When I create a testbench to test it, the reg ACC has the value of X throughout the whole waveform. I believe this is because it was not instantiated properly, and I am trying to add it to itself. How can I do this? I don't want to set it to 0 in the always@ block, because I want it's value to carry over unless I manually reset it. I already using an initial begin block, but that resulted in the values of the registers all being Z.

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

module AccAdder_Behavioral(IN, ADD, CLC, CLB, IAC, X2, ACC, CARRY
);
input[3:0] IN;
input ADD, CLC, CLB, IAC;
wire [3:0] SEL;
input X2;
output reg [3:0] ACC;
output reg CARRY;




always @(SEL) begin

case(SEL)
1: ACC = ACC + 4'b0001; //IAC 
    2: CARRY = CARRY & 0; //CLC
    4: begin 
        ACC = ACC & 4'b0000;
        CARRY = CARRY & 0;
        end //CLB
    8: ACC = ACC + IN;//ADD
endcase 

end


endmodule
```

Comment: Do you want ACC to be a flip-flop or combinatorial?

Comment: You are adding ACC to itself. Its initial value is X hence, adding it to itself causes the value to stay at x. Why don't you use an if statement with a reset signal. Set ACC to a known value when reset was 1.

Answer (score 1):

You need a clock reference if you are incrementing a signal. Otherwise you are inferring complex latching logic. Clocking example:

```
always @(posedge CLK) begin
  case(1'b1)
    IAC: ACC   <= ACC + 4'b1;
    CLC: CARRY <= 1'b0;
    CLB: begin
           ACC   <= 4'b0;
           CARRY <= 1'b0;
         end
    ADD: ACC <= ACC + IN;
  endcase
end
```